# Incrementally detecting dominators in DAGs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Suppose we have a DAG with one source. I would like to find nodes `n` such that any complete path from the source runs through `n` (i.e. `n` dominates all sinks). In other words: if we removed all the succesors of `n`, then all paths would end in `n`. The problem is that nodes are incrementally marked as deleted in the DAG. As nodes are marked deleted, other nodes can start to satisfy the above property. How can I efficiently detect this as it happens?

**Bonus points** if the data structure can do this with multiple sources in a more efficient way than running the algorithm for a single source separately on each of the sources.

Comment: That means you want incrementally determine cut in a changing graph? And do you need all such nodes (all cuts) or does one suffice?

Comment: Yes, that's another way of saying it: detecting a cut just before it happens (i.e. just before the last node is deleted that would lead to a cut).

Comment: Re: edit: preferably all such cuts, but one cut would be good enough too. Cuts should happen relatively rarely, so if it does happen it is not too big of a deal to run a slow algorithm to find the other cuts.

Comment: I don't understand why your idea fails. For each vertex `v`: remove its successors [only edges to successors to be more exact], and check if all paths end with `v` [using BFS, you did not reach any other node `u` such that `d_out(u) = 0`], if they are - `v` is a dominator. Or are you looking for a solution with better run time then quadric?

Comment: Yes, that algorithm is quadratic each time a vertex is deleted. I was looking for something closer to constant time each time a vertex is deleted, or time proportional to some measure of affected vertices. Perhaps it's possible to achieve this with the right data structure for representing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Topologically sort this DAG to establish some order for its nodes. For each node, its value would be the number of outgoing edges from all preceding nodes minus the number of incoming edges to all preceding nodes and current node. Value for "dominator" node is always zero.

After some node is marked "deleted", put its predecessors and successors to priority queue. Priority is determined by the topological sort order. Update values for all nodes, following the "deleted" node (add the number of incoming nodes and subtract the number of outgoing nodes for this node). At the same time (in same order) decrement value for each node between predecessor node in the priority queue and the "deleted" node and increment value for each node, starting from successor node in the priority queue. Stop when some node's value is decremented to zero. This is a new "dominator" node. If all "dominator" nodes needed, continue until the end of the graph.

```
delete(delNode):
  for each predecessor in delNode.predecessors: queue.add(predecessor)
  for each successor in delNode.successors: queue.add(successor)
  for each node in DAG:
    if queue.top.priority == node.priority > delNode.priority:
      ++accumulator

    node.value += accumulator
    if node.value == 0: dominatorDetected(node)

    if node.priority == delNode.priority:
      accumulator += (delNode.predecessors.size - delNode.successors.size)
      node.value = -1

    if queue.top.priority == node.priority:
      queue.pop()
      if node.priority < delNode.priority:
        --accumulator

    if queue.empty: stop
```

For multiple sources case, it is possible to use the same algorithm, but keep a list of "values" for each node, one value for each source. Algorithm complexity is `O(Nodes * Sources)`, the same as for independent search on each of the sources. But the program may be made more efficient if vectorization is used. "values" may be processed in parallel with SIMD instructions. Modern compilers may do automatic vectorization to acieve this.

Comment: Can you give a reference / proof that the value for a vertex is 0 if and only if it is a dominator? I am not sure I understand why it is true [or I don't understand the `value` definition correctly].

Comment: Amit: the nodes I'm looking for are nodes where all paths go through. So 0 edges should go parallel to that node. Incoming edges - outgoing edges before a node is equal to the number of parallel edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I will give other people a little time to write answers and upvote answers, then I will accept it :) Thanks again!

Comment: This algorithm only works when there is a single sink node right? This requirement is not a problem because it is easy to add a new sink node connected to all previous sinks.

Comment: It works with any number of sinks/sources. And it may be used with incrementally added sources (for added sources, just do the same as for deleted nodes, but inversed: decrement instead of increment and vice versa).

Comment: Can you explain how it can work for multiple sources? I am looking for nodes `n` such that there is *any* source such that *all* paths go through `n`. It seems that your algorithm finds nodes `n` such that for *all* sources *all* paths go through `n`? Maybe I didn't understand?

Comment: Right, it finds such nodes only for *all* sources.

Comment: To make it work in terms of "*any* source", it is possible to maintain an array of values for each node, one value per source.